# In the directed graph, What's the name of the node which does not have an incoming edge

Tags: graph, terminology, graph-theory

It's a terminology question:

In the directed graph, What's the name of the node which does not have any incoming edge (*root*)?

In my following example (B):

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my CS education, I remember calling nodes like B with only outgoing edges "sources", and nodes like A and D with only incoming edges "sinks".

Comment: That terminology matches my Combinatorics and Optimization education too, it also matches this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#Direction